# Multiple pages same CSS/JS file but different URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, url

I'm making a website with different pages; let's say:

- Home
- About me
- Contact

All those pages have the same structure

```
<div id="PageWrapper">
   <header id="PageHeader">
      <nav id="MainMenu">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>

   <div id="PageContent"></div>
</div>
```

where in PageContent will be filled by the page content.

Since all those pages have the same structure, I would like to have an Index.html page with the structure and then load all the contents from different html files instead of creating n pages with same structure and copying and past the link to CSS and JS files.

I've tried using function from JQuery in the following way

```
$('#MainMenu ul li a').click(function(e) { 
   appendPage($(this).attr('href'));
   e.preventDefault();
});
    
function appendPage(url){
   window.location.hash = url;
   $.ajax({
      url: url
   }).done(function(data) {
      $('#PageContent').html(data);
    });
}
```

this works but the problem is it doesn't really change the URL of the page. If I save the url and I would like to go directly to Contact page, it will reload the page from the Home

Comment: window.location.hash returns the #foo part of the page URI. You'll need to strip the hash and append something like .html and ensure that you're fetching from the correct path where your page content will be.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a folder called `pages` and ensure all your links follow the same name as your file names.

So you'd have a `pages` directory with `home.html`, `about.html`, etc.

```
<div id="PageWrapper">
   <header id="PageHeader">
      <nav id="MainMenu">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>

   <div id="PageContent"></div>
</div>
```

```
$('#MainMenu ul li a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   insertContent($(this).attr('href'));
});

function insertContent(pageHref){
   pageHref = pageHref.replace('#', '');
   $.ajax({
      url: `pages/${pageHref}.html`,
   }).done(function(data) {
      $('#PageContent').html(data);
   });
}

// Initialize content based on window location hash
window.onload = insertContent(location.hash);
```

Comment: Open up your developer console and see if it's failing to fetch the resource. In which case you'll need to ensure the path is correct.

Comment: No, it loads the right page but it doesn't change my URL so I cannot save on my library list About page

Comment: If you want to dynamically change the url like how you're describing, you need to use history.pushState

Comment: Ok, if I use history.pushState it works but the problem is, if I copy the URL and paste it in a new windows, it only opens my HTML without keeping the Javascript or CSS because they are linked only in the index.html

Comment: Understandably so. Ideally you could use a hash code instead. Then on page load you just load whatever the hash is.